# Nullable class?

Tags: c#, class, nullable

I have this class

```
public class FilterQuery
    {
        public FilterQuery() { }

        public string OrderBy { set; get; }
        public string OrderType { set; get; }        

        public int? Page { set; get; }
        public int ResultNumber { set; get; }

    }
```

I would like to use it like this

```
public IQueryable<Listing> FindAll(FilterQuery? filterQuery)
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like you want an overload, not a nullable

Comment: Then I am duplicating the code?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This immediately begs the question of *why*. Classes are by definition *reference types* and thus are already nullable. It makes no sense to wrap them in a nullable type.

In your case, you can simply define:

```
public IQueryable<Listing> FindAll(FilterQuery filterQuery)
```

and call `FindAll(null)` to pass no filter query.

If you're using C#/.NET 4.0, a nice option is:

```
public IQueryable<Listing> FindAll(FilterQuery filterQuery = null)
```

which means you don't even have to specify the null. An overload would do the same trick in previous versions.

**Edit:** Per request, the overload would simply look like:

```
public IQueryable<Listing> FindAll()
{
    return FindAll(null);
}
```

Comment: I see... but the thing is that I have relatively complex method and if I make overload I will duplicate whole method?

Answer (score 8):

There's no need to do that; all `class` types are reference types, which means that it is nullable by definition. Indeed, there is no way to *enforce* that it's *non-null* at compile time.

The `Nullable<T>` struct is designed to allow value types (which are, by definition, not null) to represent a null value.

It's also worth noting that the ability to compare `Nullable<T>` with `null` (or `Nothing` in VB.NET) is syntactic sugar; because `Nullable<T>` is a struct, it cannot actually be `null`. In the case where it represents a null value, `HasValue` is `false` and `Value` is `default(T)`.

Comment: You can enforce non-null condition at compile time by using assertions and formal verification. There is a built-in tool in Visual Studio 2008/10, if you install the Microsoft "Code Contracts" extension. But formal (static) verification works only if every part of your code is well asserted, and if your condition does not depend on a runtime one.  
Simpler : formal verification does not work.